# Cut image in the center

Tags: php

I want to cut a image in the center to another sizes... Example, the image has 500x500, I want to cut and create another archive image with 150x150 in another folder...

**Image:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require __DIR__ . '\..\configurations.inc.php';
sleep(1);

$form = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

$upload = new Upload($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'uploads/links/photos');
$upload->Image($_FILES['ADD_FIGURE']);

if(!$upload->getResult()):
    echo '1';    
else:
$PHOTO = $upload->getResult();

echo $PHOTO;
endif;
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"I want"* isn't a question. Also it doesn't appear that you have made any attempts to solve this yourself. Do some basic research and ask questions when you have some actual code that isn't working as expected. If you have made attempts...please show the code you tried. This isn't a code writing or tutorial service